# Creating a shopping cart plugin using php and displaying plugin on a wordpress page

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

so I'm new to coding and I`ve been given a  task of creating a quotation plugin in WordPress (shopping cart) where someone can select what items that are available (which is stored in database *phpmyadmin*) , allow the user to input the quantity of the products and display the total.

I`m having trouble in understanding the procedure to write the functions to execute the task, and displaying it on a word press post.

First File ( Creation of database )

```
<?php


function quotations_database(){
   global $wpdb; 
   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix. 'shop_cart';
   $shop_cart_db_version = '1.0.0' ;


       $sql_query = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
       id mediumint(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       productnames varchar (116) NOT NULL,
       code varchar(100) NOT NULL,
       image varchar(250) NOT NULL,
       productprice INT(50) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
       )";

       $inserting = "INSERT INTO `wp_shop_cart` (`id`, `productname`, `code`, `image`, `productprice`) VALUES ('001', 'Devil May Cry ', 'DMC61616', '', '500'), ('002', 'Kyle Will Cry ', 'KWC2929', '', '10000')";


   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
   dbDelta( $sql_query ); // is to create and update tables. :( //



   add_option('shop_cart_db_version', $shop_cart_db_version);


}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array( 'DB_creation.php', 'quotations_database' ) );
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,array('DB_creation.php','quoatations_database') );
?>
```

Second File (Creation of Database)

```
     <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Quotation
 * Plugin URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/my-first-plugin
 * Description: The very first plugin that I have ever created.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Help me please :(
 * Author URI: http://www.mywebsite.com
 */ 


if (!defined('ABSPATH')){
    define('ABSPATH',  dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__,"quotations_database");

php?>
```

Third File ( Functionality of Plugin/ of what i have so far  )

```
<?php

?>


<form action="">
  :<br>
  <input type="text" name="Name of Prouduct" value="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Amount Wanted" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 



<?php
function testing(){
    $product_array = get_result->($wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_shop_cart` ORDER BY id ASC " ); ?>)

        if(!empty($product_array)){     //Checks if the results have vaules

            foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
                ?>
                <div class="product-item">
                    <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
                        <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>"></div>
                        <div class="product-tile-footer">
                            <div class="product-title"><?php echo $product_array[$key]["productname"]; ?></div>
                            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "$".$product_array[$key]["productprice"]; ?></div>
                            <div class="cart-action"><input type="text" class="product-quantity" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /><input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btnAddAction" /></div> 
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>          }

                <?php-
                add shortcode['example','testing'];
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to S.O.!  The question you posed is well formatted, however it's lacking focus a bit at the moment. I would suggest digging into wordpress tutorials a bit more, until you have some questions that can be answered in a more straightforward manner. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for response , My question is how create a shopping cart plugin  using php  and to output code on wordpress.. Is it clearer ?

Comment: Here is a simple example of of that: https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/ecommerce/simple-wp-shopping-cart-installation-usage-290
But I believe what you are looking for is more like a tutorial, than a question..